# I want to format my output of perl

Tags: perl

I am getting following output:

```
"I"=> ["Isoleucine","Ile",["ATT,ATC,ATA"]];
"L"=> ["Leucine","Leu",["TTA,TTG,CTT,CTC,CTA,CTG"]];
"K"=> ["Lysine","Lys",["AAA,AAG"]];
```

when I use the code

```
foreach(@genetic_codes){
  chomp;
  my @genetic_codes = split(':',$_);
  if(@genetic_codes != 5){
    # error on this line
    next;
  }
  my $group = join(',',split(/,\s*/,$genetic_codes[4]));
  print "$genetic_codes[2]=> [$genetic_codes[0],$genetic_codes[1],[$group]];\n";
}
```

How can i get rid of double quotes around my key?

Comment: What does the input look like?

Comment: From your own answer to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491893) (it should really have been a comment) you say you don't want to use `Text::CSV`. I wonder why that is? Installing modules is very straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I would forget about `split`, and use a regular expression to find all substrings that aren't either a colon or a quote. That will trim the quotes automatically.

This program will do what you want. It uses the data from your previous question.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "my %amino_acids = (\n";

while (<DATA>) {
  my @data = /[^:"]+/g;
  my @codons = $data[4] =~ /[A-Z]+/g;
  printf qq{  %s => ["%s", "%s", [%s]],\n},
      @data[2,0,1],
      join ', ', map qq{"$_"}, @codons;
}

print ")\n";

__DATA__
"Methionine":"Met":"M":"AUG":"ATG"
"Phenylalanine":"Phe":"F":"UUU, UUC":"TTT, TTC"
"Proline":"Pro":"P":"CCU, CCC, CCA, CCG":"CCT, CCC, CCA, CCG"
```

**output**

```
my %amino_acids = (
  M => ["Methionine", "Met", ["ATG"]],
  F => ["Phenylalanine", "Phe", ["TTT", "TTC"]],
  P => ["Proline", "Pro", ["CCT", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG"]],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The double quotes seem to be part of their respective strings. This indicates that your parsing may be broken. The loop you gave as code example doesn't make much sense either (redefining the variable you are looping over inside the loop, even if that should be harmless, is bad style).

It seems you would like

```
my @genetic_codes = /(?:\A|(?<=:)) "([^"]*)" (?=:|\z)/xg; # not tested
...;
```

or

```
my @genetic_codes = split /:/;
s/^"//, s/"$// for @genetic_codes;
...;
```

or something along these lines.

The first possibility replaces your `split` by a roughly equivalent regex application with `/g` and list context.

The second solution might be preferable and removes all leading and trailing whitespace from all elements in the `@genetic_codes`. This solution may be more flexible and less error-prone.

Tip: Instead of the split/join you could just do

```
(my $group = $genetic_codes[4]) =~ s/(?<=,)\s+//g; # remove whitespace after every comma
```